# "A large number of messages are being sent" warning. How to get around it?

Tags: sms

I have a stand alone SMS Sender application that needs to send messages to certain mobile numbers. The messages to be sent can go over 1000 or more. Upon testing the app, I encountered a warning dialog, which I understand is a native warning from android OS, saying that a large number of messages are being sent whenever the app is sending the 101st (and so on) message. It will only send the message if I click on OK. I need to bypass this warning. Does anybody know a work-around. I'm using API 7.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a gateway server? Sending a single request to a gateway server to tell it to send the messages would use less bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Its rather old, but there is rate-limit information [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/587f0d3a03ced88a): it requires root, so I think you're probably out of luck there. The check appears to default to 100 messages every hour: after that the check is triggered.